# Entity Framework - Performance in count

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I've a little question about performance with Entity Framework.

Something like

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    Document DocObject = context.Document.Find(_id);
    int GroupCount = context.Document.Where(w=>w.Group == DocObject.Group).ToList().Count();
}
```

takes about 2 seconds in my database (about 30k datasets), while this one

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    Document DocObject = context.Document.Find(_id);
    int GroupCount = context.Document.Where(w=>w.Group == DocObject.Group).Count();
}
```

takes 0,02 seconds.

When my filter for 10 documents had 20 seconds to wait, I checked my code, and changed this to not use `ToList()` before `Count()`.

Any ideas why it needs 2 seconds for this line with the `ToList()`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Calling `ToList()` then `Count()` will:

- execute the whole `SELECT FROM WHERE` against your database
- then materialize all the resulting entities as .Net objects
- create a new `List<T>` object containing all the results
- return the result of the `Count` property of the .Net list you just created

Calling `Count()` against an `IQueryable` will:

- execute `SELECT COUNT FROM WHERE` against your database
- return an `Int32` with the number of rows

Obviously, if you're only interested in the number of items (**not the items themselves**), then you shouldn't ever call `ToList()` first, as it will require a lot of resources for nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `ToList()` will evaluate the results (retrieving the objects from database), if you do not use `ToList()`, the objects aren´t retrieved from the database.

Linq-To-Entities uses LazyLoading per default.

It works something like this;
When you query your underlying DB connection using Linq-To-Entities you will get a proxy object back on which you can perform a number of operations (count being one). This means that you do not get all the data from the DB at once but rather the objects are retrieved from the DB at the time of evaluation. One way of evaluating the object is by using ToList().

Maybe you should read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Comment: This answer is not correct. The issue has nothing to do with *lazy loading* or deferred execution; both queries will be "eagerly" executed: the first due to `ToList()`, the second due to `Count()`. The *difference* is that the second query is *optimized* to a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query which is a lot faster.

Comment: This is semantics. I never stated that Count() would not eagerly execute, but the object returned from the Where-method will be of the type IQuerable<T> which is a proxy object whereas ToList() will perform a full select and will eagerly load the entire objects. Count() is performed in both examples, in the latter it is performed on the IQueryable<T> and in the first it is performed on the evaluated List<T>. The reason for the performance loss is definitely due to performing a full SELECT and not SELECT COUNT(*) which in this case is the result of eagerly loading the objects using ToList.

Comment: I don't want to get into a discussion about this. The truth of the matter is that the second solution is *faster* because the EF optimizes the `DB` query to a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query, a fact that you do not state anywhere in your answer. You simply reffer to lazy loading, deffered execution and now  `IQuerable<T>` which has nothing to do with the issue. In the second option `Count()` *also eagerly* executes the query and loads the "object(s)". The difference is that the query has been optimized at the query level and therefore returns one single value.

Comment: It is not an "optimization" - it´s a different query, and why is it a different query? Because in the first example, the ToList method will **eagerly** load the entire objects (performing a full SELECT), and in the latter it wont (performing a SELECT COUNT(*) on Count()).

Comment: Of course its an optimization, what else would it be? The code is suboptimal, the framework understands this common scenario and therefore optimizes the query for you to a `SELECT COUNT(*)` because otherwise in order to *count* the objects it would first have to execute the query, exactly the same as if you'd done `ToList()`. In order to count something, you need to iterate through the whole thing or how would you do it otherwise? `Count()` eagerly executes any query, same as `ToList()` does. If you are not convinced, then just do some debugging with in-memory objects.

Comment: I am aware that Count() will "eagerly execute", I never stated otherwise.
Ok, so digging to the core;

Do you agree that by doing ToList you will load the entire objects?
Do you agree that ToList().Count() and Count() will result in different queries?
Do you agree that Where() will return and IQueryable and ToList() will return a full List?

Now, go back and read what I have stated in my response.

Answer (score 4):

Because `ToList()` will query the database for the whole objects (will do a `SELECT *` so to say), and then you'll use `Count()` on the list in memory with all the records, whereas if you use `Count()` on the `IQueryable` (and not on the `List`), EF will translate it to a simple `SELECT COUNT(*)` SQL query

Answer (score 2):

Your first query isnt fully transalted to sql - when you call `.ToList().Count()`, you are basically saying "download all, materialize it to POCO and call extension method named `Count()`" which, of course, take some time.

Your second query is, however, transalted to something like `select count(*) from Documents where GroupId = @DocObjectGroup` which is much faster to execute and you arent materializing anything, just simple scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Using the extension method `Enumerable.ToList()` will construct a new List object from the `IEnumerable<T>` source collection which means that there is an associated cost with doing `ToList()`.